# android- which Thread does run onSensorChanged?

Tags: java, android, android-sensors

if I attach a listener to a sensor of the device (like below), in this situation while onSensorChanged happens, which thread does run `generateNewRotation` method, main Thread or...?

```
SensorEventListener sensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

            generateNewRotation();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OnSensorChanged()` gets called inside the Main Thread, also called the UI Thread.

Comment: Also, I find a question which is similar to yours.                   `2) Does the onSensorChanged function run on different threads other than the activity thread?`

**It runs on a different thread which is dependent on the activity it has been appended to (the activity that either implemented the SensorEventListener interface or contains an object instantiated from an anonymous inner class created on the SensorEventListener object).** [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743271/info-on-onsensorchanged-of-android-acccelerometer) is the link. Hope this can help you.