# Android Application freeze with Android 11

Tags: java, android

Working on the development of an android app to log GNSS and sensor data. the App works fine with Android 10 but with Android 11, the App screen gets freeze after setting a switch ON. However, the data logging (which is the main goal of the Application) still works in the background with both Android versions. Thank you in advance.

```
public class SensorFragment extends Fragment implements SensorEventListener {

    Switch Calibrated_logSensor;
    Switch Uncalibrated_logSensor;
    Switch logRnx_calibrated_Sensor;
    Switch logRnx_uncalibrated_Sensor;
    boolean sensorState = false;
    boolean lastSensorState = false;
    boolean sensorState2 = false;
    boolean lastSensorState2 = false;
    final long starttime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    Chronometer sensorChronometer;
    Boolean _areLecturesLoaded =false;

    RinexLogger mRinexLogger;
    boolean header_exist = false;

    //the Sensor Manager
    private SensorManager sManager;
    private Sensor mSensor;
    private File csv = null;
    private File csv2 = null;
    

    GraphicalView accView;
    GraphicalView gyroView;
    GraphicalView magView;

    private int accCount = 0;
    private int gyroCount = 0;
    private int magCount = 0;
    public static long gpstimeoffset = 0;
    long gpstimemilli =0 ;
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer accMultipleRenderer;
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer gyroMultipleRenderer;
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer magMultipleRenderer;

    long test;
    public File createSensorLog_calibration() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        File folder;
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state))
        {
            File folder_root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "GNSS-INS Logger");
            folder_root.mkdir();
            folder = new File(folder_root, "Calibr_IMU_Log");
            folder.mkdir();
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
        String filedate = dateFormat.format(new Date());
        String filename = Build.MODEL + "_IMU_" + filedate + "." + "txt";
        csv = new File(folder, filename);// Filename
        return csv;
    }
    public File createSensorLog_uncalibration() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        File folder;
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state))
        {
            File folder_root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "GNSS-INS Logger");
            folder_root.mkdir();
            folder = new File(folder_root, "Uncalibr_IMU_Log");
            folder.mkdir();
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
        String filedate = dateFormat.format(new Date());
        String filename2 = Build.MODEL + "_IMU_" + filedate + "." + "txt";
        csv2 = new File(folder, filename2);// Filename
        return csv2;
    }

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sensor, container, false);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //timestampmag = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timestampmag);

        //test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        //get a hook to the sensor service
        sManager = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mSensor = sManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyddMMhhmmss");
        String filename = "Sensorlog" + "_" + df.format(new Date()) + "." + "txt";

    /*    Button startBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.sendEmail);
        startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendEmail();
            }
            // graph.addSeries(series);
        });*/

        // From here the chartEngine is set up        
        // Renderers that control the accelerometer graphs

        Calibrated_logSensor = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.calibrsensorLog);
        Uncalibrated_logSensor = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.uncalibrsensorLog);
        logRnx_calibrated_Sensor = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.calibrsensorRnxLog);
        logRnx_uncalibrated_Sensor = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.uncalibrsensorRnxLog);

        XYSeriesRenderer accXRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        accXRenderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        accXRenderer.setLineWidth(8);
        XYSeriesRenderer accYRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        accYRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
        accYRenderer.setLineWidth(8);
        XYSeriesRenderer accZRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        accZRenderer.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        accZRenderer.setLineWidth(5);

        //Dataset that host the series which are continuously appended with sensor values

        XYMultipleSeriesDataset accDataSet = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        accDataSet.addSeries(accX);
        accDataSet.addSeries(accY);
        accDataSet.addSeries(accZ);

        //the MultipleSeriesRenderer that combines the single graphs

        accMultipleRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        accMultipleRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(accXRenderer);
        accMultipleRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(accYRenderer);
        accMultipleRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(accZRenderer);
        accMultipleRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
        accMultipleRenderer.setGridLineWidth(8);
        accMultipleRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00));
        accMultipleRenderer.setLegendTextSize(25);
        accMultipleRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(25);
        accMultipleRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0,Color.BLACK);
        accMultipleRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
        accMultipleRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true, true);
        accMultipleRenderer.setPanEnabled(false, true);
        accMultipleRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
        accMultipleRenderer.setYTitle("m/s^2");
        accMultipleRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(25);
        accMultipleRenderer.setXTitle("                                                                                            Epoch (milliseconds)");
        accMultipleRenderer.setXLabels(0);
        accMultipleRenderer.setChartTitle("Calibrated Accelerometer vs Time");
        accMultipleRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(30);

        //set up the Linear layout and add the graphs

        LinearLayout accLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.plotAcc);
        accView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(getContext(), accDataSet, accMultipleRenderer);
        accLayout.addView(accView);

        // Renderers that control the gyroscope graphs

        XYSeriesRenderer gyroXRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        gyroXRenderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        gyroXRenderer.setLineWidth(8);
        XYSeriesRenderer gyroYRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        gyroYRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
        gyroYRenderer.setLineWidth(8);
        XYSeriesRenderer gyroZRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        gyroZRenderer.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        gyroZRenderer.setLineWidth(5);

        //Dataset that host the series which are continuously appended with sensor values

        XYMultipleSeriesDataset gyroDataSet = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        gyroDataSet.addSeries(gyroX);
        gyroDataSet.addSeries(gyroY);
        gyroDataSet.addSeries(gyroZ);

        //the MultipleSeriesRenderer that combines the single graphs

        gyroMultipleRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        gyroMultipleRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(gyroXRenderer);
        gyroMultipleRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(gyroYRenderer);
        gyroMultipleRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(gyroZRenderer);
        gyroMultipleRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
        gyroMultipleRenderer.setGridLineWidth(8);
        gyroMultipleRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00));
        gyroMultipleRenderer.setLegendTextSize(25);
        gyroMultipleRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(25);
        gyroMultipleRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0,Color.BLACK);
        gyroMultipleRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
        gyroMultipleRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true, true);
        gyroMultipleRenderer.setPanEnabled(false, true);
        gyroMultipleRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
        gyroMultipleRenderer.setYTitle("rad/s");
        gyroMultipleRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(25);
        gyroMultipleRenderer.setXTitle("                                                                                            Epoch (milliseconds)");
        gyroMultipleRenderer.setXLabels(0);
        gyroMultipleRenderer.setChartTitle("Calibrated Gyroscope vs Time");
        gyroMultipleRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(30);


        //set up the Linear layout and add the graphs

        LinearLayout gyroLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.plotGyro);
        gyroView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(getContext(), gyroDataSet, gyroMultipleRenderer);
        gyroLayout.addView(gyroView);

        //and the same for the magnetometer rendering        
        XYSeriesRenderer magXRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        magXRenderer.setLineWidth(8);
        magXRenderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        XYSeriesRenderer magYRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        magYRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
        magYRenderer.setLineWidth(8);

        XYSeriesRenderer magZRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        magZRenderer.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        magZRenderer.setLineWidth(5);

        XYMultipleSeriesDataset magDataSet = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        magDataSet.addSeries(magX);
        magDataSet.addSeries(magY);
        magDataSet.addSeries(magZ);

        magMultipleRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        magMultipleRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(magXRenderer);
        magMultipleRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(magYRenderer);
        magMultipleRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(magZRenderer);
        magMultipleRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
        magMultipleRenderer.setGridLineWidth(8);
        magMultipleRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00));
        magMultipleRenderer.setLegendTextSize(25);
        gyroMultipleRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(25);
        magMultipleRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0,Color.BLACK);
        magMultipleRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
        magMultipleRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true, true);
        magMultipleRenderer.setPanEnabled(false, true);
        magMultipleRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
        magMultipleRenderer.setXTitle("                                                                                             Epoch (milliseconds)");
        magMultipleRenderer.setYTitle("µT");
        magMultipleRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(25);
        magMultipleRenderer.setXLabels(0);

      //  LinearLayout magLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.plotMag);
        magView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(getContext(), magDataSet, magMultipleRenderer);
      //  magLayout.addView(magView);

        sensorChronometer = (Chronometer) view.findViewById(R.id.sensor_chronometer);
        TextView chronoSensorText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sensor_timer_display);
        chronoSensorText.setText("Log Duration:");

        return view;

    }
   
    //when this Activity starts
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        /*register the sensor listener to listen to the gyroscope sensor, use the
         * callbacks defined in this class, and gather the sensor information as
         * quick as possible*/
        //if (Uncalibrated_logSensor.isChecked() || logRnx_uncalibrated_Sensor.isChecked()) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            sManager.registerListener(this, sManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER_UNCALIBRATED), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        }
        sManager.registerListener(this, sManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE_UNCALIBRATED), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
            sManager.registerListener(this, sManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD_UNCALIBRATED), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);// }
       // else {
            sManager.registerListener(this, sManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
            sManager.registerListener(this, sManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
            sManager.registerListener(this, sManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        //    }
    }

  

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        if(Uncalibrated_logSensor.isChecked() || Calibrated_logSensor.isChecked()){
            sensorState=true;
        }
        if(!(Uncalibrated_logSensor.isChecked() || Calibrated_logSensor.isChecked())){
            sensorState = false;
        }
        if(sensorState&& !lastSensorState){
            csv = createSensorLog_calibration();
            csv2 = createSensorLog_uncalibration();
            header_exist = false;
            sensorChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            sensorChronometer.start();

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "File opened: " + csv.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "File opened: " + csv2.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        lastSensorState = sensorState;
        //if sensor is unreliable, return void
        //if (event.accuracy == SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE) {
         //   return;
        //}
        if(logRnx_uncalibrated_Sensor.isChecked() || logRnx_calibrated_Sensor.isChecked()){
            sensorState2=true;
        }
        if(!(logRnx_uncalibrated_Sensor.isChecked() || logRnx_calibrated_Sensor.isChecked())){
            sensorState2 = false;
        }
        if(sensorState2&& !lastSensorState2){
            csv = createSensorLog_calibration();
            csv2 = createSensorLog_uncalibration();
            mRinexLogger.startNewLog();
            header_exist = false;
            sensorChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            sensorChronometer.start();
        }
        lastSensorState2 = sensorState2;

        if(!(logRnx_uncalibrated_Sensor.isChecked() || logRnx_calibrated_Sensor.isChecked()) && !(Uncalibrated_logSensor.isChecked() || Calibrated_logSensor.isChecked())){
            sensorChronometer.stop();
        }

        Sensor sensor = event.sensor;

        long timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() + ((event.timestamp - SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()) / 1000000L);
        long eventtimeMillis =  (event.timestamp ) / 1000000L;

        if(gpstimeoffset == 0){
            gpstimemilli = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            gpstimemilli = (gpstimeoffset + event.timestamp)/1000000L;
        }

        if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            //TODO: get value
            int sensor_type = 1;

            accCount++;

            if (accCount % 2 == 0) {

                accX.add(timeInMillis, event.values[0]);
                accY.add(timeInMillis, event.values[1]);
                accZ.add(timeInMillis, event.values[2]);


                if (accCount > 1000) {
                    accX.remove(0);
                    accY.remove(0);
                    accZ.remove(0);
                }

                accView.repaint();
                if(accCount%500 ==0)
                    accMultipleRenderer.addXTextLabel(timeInMillis, Long.toString(SystemClock.uptimeMillis()-starttime));
            }
            if(Calibrated_logSensor.isChecked()){
                try {
                    writeSensorLog_calibr(timeInMillis,gpstimemilli,sensor_type,Float.toString(event.values[0]), Float.toString(event.values[1]), Float.toString(event.values[2]),csv);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(logRnx_calibrated_Sensor.isChecked()){
                try {
                    writeSensorLog_calibr(timeInMillis,gpstimemilli,sensor_type,Float.toString(event.values[0]), Float.toString(event.values[1]), Float.toString(event.values[2]),csv);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        else if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER_UNCALIBRATED) {
            //TODO: get value
            int sensor_type = 1;
            if(Uncalibrated_logSensor.isChecked()){
                try {
                    writeSensorLog_uncalibr(eventtimeMillis,sensor_type,Float.toString(event.values[0]), Float.toString(event.values[1]), Float.toString(event.values[2]),csv2);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(logRnx_uncalibrated_Sensor.isChecked()){
                try {
                    writeSensorLog_uncalibr_withrnx(timeInMillis,gpstimemilli,sensor_type,Float.toString(event.values[0]), Float.toString(event.values[1]), Float.toString(event.values[2]),csv2);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } }

        }
        else if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {
            //TODO: get values
            int sensor_type = 2;
            gyroCount++;

            if (gyroCount % 2 == 0) {

                gyroX.add(timeInMillis, event.values[0]);
                gyroY.add(timeInMillis, event.values[1]);
                gyroZ.add(timeInMillis, event.values[2]);

                if (gyroCount > 1000) {
                    gyroX.remove(0);
                    gyroY.remove(0);
                    gyroZ.remove(0);
                }

                gyroView.repaint();
            }
            if(accCount%500==0) {
                gyroMultipleRenderer.addXTextLabel(timeInMillis, Long.toString(SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - starttime));
            }
            if(Calibrated_logSensor.isChecked()){
                try {
                    writeSensorLog_calibr(timeInMillis,gpstimemilli,sensor_type,Float.toString(event.values[0]), Float.toString(event.values[1]), Float.toString(event.values[2]),csv);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(logRnx_calibrated_Sensor.isChecked()){
                try {
                    writeSensorLog_calibr(timeInMillis,gpstimemilli,sensor_type,Float.toString(event.values[0]), Float.toString(event.values[1]), Float.toString(event.values[2]),csv);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        else if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE_UNCALIBRATED) {
            //TODO: get values
            int sensor_type = 2;
            if(Uncalibrated_logSensor.isChecked()){
                try {
                    writeSensorLog_uncalibr(eventtimeMillis,sensor_type,Float.toString(event.values[0]), Float.toString(event.values[1]), Float.toString(event.values[2]),csv2);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(logRnx_uncalibrated_Sensor.isChecked()){
                try {
                    writeSensorLog_uncalibr_withrnx(timeInMillis,gpstimemilli,sensor_type,Float.toString(event.values[0]), Float.toString(event.values[1]), Float.toString(event.values[2]),csv2);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        else if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
            //TODO: get values
            int sensor_type = 3;
            magCount++;
            magX.add(timeInMillis, event.values[0]);
            magY.add(timeInMillis, event.values[1]);
            magZ.add(timeInMillis, event.values[2]);
            if(accCount%500==0) {
                magMultipleRenderer.addXTextLabel(timeInMillis, Long.toString(SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - starttime));
            }

            if (magCount > 180) {
                magX.remove(0);
                magY.remove(0);
                magZ.remove(0);
            }
            magView.repaint();

            if(Calibrated_logSensor.isChecked()){
                try {
                    writeSensorLog_calibr(timeInMillis,gpstimemilli,sensor_type,Float.toString(event.values[0]), Float.toString(event.values[1]), Float.toString(event.values[2]),csv);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(logRnx_calibrated_Sensor.isChecked()){
                try {
                    writeSensorLog_calibr(timeInMillis,gpstimemilli,sensor_type,Float.toString(event.values[0]), Float.toString(event.values[1]), Float.toString(event.values[2]),csv);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        else if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD_UNCALIBRATED) {
            //TODO: get values
            int sensor_type = 3;
            if(Uncalibrated_logSensor.isChecked()){
                try {
                    writeSensorLog_uncalibr(eventtimeMillis,sensor_type,Float.toString(event.values[0]), Float.toString(event.values[1]), Float.toString(event.values[2]),csv2);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(logRnx_uncalibrated_Sensor.isChecked()){
                try {
                    writeSensorLog_uncalibr_withrnx(timeInMillis,gpstimemilli,sensor_type,Float.toString(event.values[0]), Float.toString(event.values[1]), Float.toString(event.values[2]),csv2);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void setRinexLogger(RinexLogger value) {
        mRinexLogger = value;
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/plotAcc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
       android:orientation="horizontal" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/plotGyro"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <Switch
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/uncalibrsensorLog"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
          android:text="@string/log_uncalibrated_sensor_data" />
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <Switch
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:id="@+id/calibrsensorLog"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
          android:text="@string/log_calibrated_sensor_data" />
  </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <Switch
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:id="@+id/uncalibrsensorRnxLog"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
          android:text="@string/log_rinex_and_uncalibrated_sensor_data" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <Switch
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:id="@+id/calibrsensorRnxLog"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
          android:text="@string/log_rinex_and_calibrated_sensor_data" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          tools:ignore="ExtraText">
          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/sensor_timer_display"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:background="#C2BBB4"
              android:textStyle="bold" />
          <Chronometer
              android:id="@+id/sensor_chronometer"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:background="#C2BBB4"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:textStyle="bold" />​
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: without single line of code no one can help you, post some relevant lines

Comment: That's a lot of code. Where specifically in the code are you seeing this issue?

Comment: @Michael the problem I have in my code is during the execution of the switch widget (e.g "Calibrated_logSensor") used for logging the sensor data. as soon I set the switch to ON, my App freezes. however, the logging still works. I see this problem only in Android 11 (works fine with 10).

Comment: Apparently [`onSensorChanged`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536677/android-which-thread-does-run-onsensorchanged) will be called on the UI thread. You execute possibly heavy I/O operations in that thread, which is almost certainly a bad idea and could behave quite differently between Android releases.